# Gap at origin when using axis lines*=left in conjunction with line width spec via axis line style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Please forgive the strange graph displayed here - I am simply trying to display a replicable chunk of code in the presence of all the packages I am attempting to use and want to avoid displaying data generated outside of my tex code. Whatever solution I come up would ideally generalize to `groupplot` (i.e. I am trying to avoid drawing my axes from scratch via `\draw`). I am attempting to compile this in XeLaTeX.

The following chunk:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\definecolor{nice_blue}{HTML}{377EB8}
\definecolor{nice_green}{HTML}{4DAF4A}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (.75,4.5) {\fontspec{Arial}w\textsubscript{1}};
\node at (1.25,5) {\fontspec{Arial}w\textsubscript{2}};
\node at (1.75,5.45) {\fontspec{Arial}w\textsubscript{3}};
\node[color=nice_green] at (5.35,3.5) {\fontspec{Arial}Well-being};
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=12,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=12,
    xlabel=\fontspec{Arial}Household Produced Investments x\textsubscript{ch},
    ylabel=\fontspec{Arial}Market Purchased Investments x\textsubscript{cm},
    axis line style = {line width=2.83464567pt},
    enlarge x limits=false
]
\addplot[->, nice_blue, line width=2.83464567pt] plot coordinates{(1,1)(5,5)};
\addplot[->, nice_green, line width=2.83464567pt] plot coordinates{(7,7)(8.5,9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Should yield the following plot:

[image]

I would like to know how to get a clean "mitred" corner in my axis with no gap as opposed to the gap shown in the zoomed image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this configuration changing the line as below would fix it.

```
axis line style = {line width=2.83464567pt,shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth},
```

Since the axis lines are drawn separately in this particular case, it might not be worth to force a line join there by other means.

[image]